# ServiceStack DeserializeFromString not settings Fields

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string "{Hints:6}" into a class using ServiceStack.Text. Below is a test case. The problem is that the console prints out 0 instead of 6. So it seems that the '*Hints*' Field in '*HintsCount*' class is not being set to the new value.

```
public class HintsCount
{
    public int Hints { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hintsCount = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<HintsCount>("{Hints:6}");

        Console.WriteLine(hintsCount.Hints);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Console prints out '0' instead of expected '6'.**

Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hintsCount = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<HintsCount>(@"{""Hints"":6}");
```

or

```
var hintsCount = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<HintsCount>("{\"Hints\":6}");
```

Comment: In your case json string has invalid format. You can validate any json string on http://jsonlint.com/. {"Hints": 6} - valid, but {Hints: 6} invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Note this isn't valid JSON:

```
"{Hints:6}"
```

[JSON requires](http://json.org/) that all properties names of object literals be quoted, try instead:

```
"{\"Hints\":6}"
```

You can just serialize the model to find out what the correct JSON should be, e.g:

```
new HintsCount { Hints = 6 }.ToJson().Print();
```

Comment: Isn't 'Hints' in the code above a public property? adding your line of code still didn't change the result, whether I have Hints as a public field or property.

Comment: right, missed it - it's because it's invalid JSON - updated answer.